# deface gem trying to modify frozen array "eager_load_paths" when running in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, spree, deface

I'm trying to deploy my spree project to heroku, but I'm getting the following error message: "Unable to load application: RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Array"

Using the backtrace, this is because deface is calling reject! method on eager_load_paths (deface/railtie.rb:39, using deface 1.1.0). It seems like this is a problem because that eager_load_paths array has already been frozen by railties (lib/rail/engine.rb:571, using rails 5.0.1)?

This doesn't break in development, but for some reason prevents me from opening up my app in production. Any guesses?

Comment: Do you remember what was the issue ? As i am facing something similar now

Comment: @RahulDess sorry, I don't. I do remember that I ended up switching away from Spree to use Solidus instead, and I think I stopped using Deface so much, by just overriding files from the gem in my repository (eg, if spree had a view at `[sample-gem-folder]/app/views/spree/example.erb.html` I made one in `[my-app]/app/views/spree/example.erb.html`.). But I don't remember if I did either of these as a direct response to this problem or just a number of problems that were adding up. Sorry I can't be more helpful. It would have been nice if someone had an answer for this two years ago!

Comment: Of course I didn't have an answer to contribute either haha, so not casting blame, just saying that I wish I could help, but can't

Comment: no worries. Actually i figured out the issue causing in my case.

Comment: @RahulDess If it solved your issue, do you mind posting an answer to share with others who run across this issue?

Comment: In my case, it was specific to `OmniAuth` Gem  using `Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do` twice both in `initializer` and in `lib` folder. Had to remove in one of the places.